# Failure when comparing a Int value to a formatted string to Int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to compare a number entered into a UITextField to a declared constant Int.  Below is my current code and it keeps failing on the if statement.

(It took me awhile to find the code to convert the UITextField to an Int as it looks like it changed after 2.0 away from the toInt() that was previously used.)

My end objective here is to eventually have several UITextFields that have user inputs that are compared to constants and then depending on whether they are < or > it will generate a recommendation.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var fshNumber: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mdMessage: UILabel!


@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fshLimit:Int = 100
    var fshInt = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(fshNumber.text)!.integerValue
    if (fshLimit>fshInt) {
        mdMessage.text = "You need help"
    } else {
        mdMessage.text = "You'll be okay"
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by failing?

Comment: You are providing the value of `fshNumber.text`, print it and add that to the question. Better yet provide a self contained example. When I substitute "100: or "99" I get the expected result. Use the debugger and print(). Factor out things like `fshNumber.text` into intermediate statements for debugging.

Comment: In Swift 2.0, `str.toInt()` has been replaced with `Int(str)`.  Note that returns an optional as before.  You should probably unwrap it with optional binding `if let fshInt = Int(fshNumber.text) {` to avoid crashes due to user input.

Comment: jtbandes - the build loads, but once I put a number in the fshNumber UITextField and then hit the button it activates the debugger, but the only message I see is (11db) and it shows fshInt = (Int) 100, fshLimit = (Int) 100.  the breakpoint appears at the if statement with Thread 1:breakpoint 1.1

Comment: So I realized that I had a manual breakpoint inserted and I removed that which allowed the app to continue to flow, but for some reason the button wasn't doing anything at all.  I did the println() and when you clicked the button it did nothing.  I couldn't quite figure out what the story was with that so I just simply removed the button and added it again and connected it to the view.. voila.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var fshInt = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(fshNumber.text)!.integerValue
```

Use this instead:

```
var fshInt = (fshNumber.text as NSString).integerValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet!